# Version control: merging changes between dev and live sites

Tags: wordpress, git, github, version-control

I am new to version control such as git so this may be an easy answer for some... for all my searching I can't find a simple enough answer.

I am developing a wordpress site on a dev server. Another developer is making changes to the live (production) site and some changes are also ftp'ed to the dev site.

Is there a way for me to merge those changes to my local copy so I don't override his changes and he doesn't override mine?

I would hate to push a file to the live site that doesn't have his changes and screw the live site up...

Comment: You can't overwrite stuff, that's not a concern you should have. Git will not let you push changes that would overwrite remote changes.

Comment: I'm not sure if he's using any version control... Does it matter?

Comment: It's really hard to say. If he's not "using version control", what is he doing? Just writing files to the Git directory and never committing his changes?

Comment: As far as I know he's just ftp'ing files to the live site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a `git pull` before trying to push your changes to the remote.

It's always a good practice to get hold of the latest `master` branch (assuming that's used on your dev server) before you

- start working on your feature branch
- push your code

Ideally, before you start working on a feature, get your feature branch to branch off from the latest `master`. You can do a `git fetch <remote_name>` and then do this -

`git checkout -b <feature_branch> <remote_name>/master`

Or better yet, merge the remote `master` in your local `master` and then create the feature branch from your local `master`.

This will ensure that your  is created off the latest `master` on your dev server.

When you cannot push to the dev server, you can do a `git pull` which will fetch and merge the latest `master`, to ensure that any of your co-workers' work is included in your work. After you do that, you will not have any issues pushing your code.

Comment: Sorry didn't know how. Did a search.